# Close a popup window that has been redirected

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net

I'm having an issue getting a popup window to close on my page using JavaScript

I've been able to get other popup windows to close, but I think I'm losing something when I end up redirecting the popup window. For example, on the main window I select a project and the popup appears giving the information. Next I click on edit which does a response redirect to the edit page. Here I do my changes and hit submit. Upon submission I want it to close but I can't seem to get it to do that.

For previous popups I would use

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CLOSE", "CloseAndRefresh();", true);
```

To call the javascript I have sitting in my .aspx file. Which is this:

```
function CloseAndRefresh() {
    parent.location.reload(true);
    parent.ClosePopup();
}
```

I generated the popup window with the following code:

```
editButton.OnClientClick = (popupWindow.GetTargetPopupCode("MYURL"));
```

This however isn't working anymore. I think that due to my redirection of the original popup window it's throwing everything off. Any idea what I need to fix?

Edit:

I've finally got to the point that the javascript is actually getting called.

I've tried these functions and none have worked:

```
window.close();
self.close();
parent.ClosePopUp();

ww = window.open(window.location, "_self");
ww.close();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you might be doing things to closely together. Adding a timeout might help. This is code that I use to refresh the parent and close a popup. Adapt this, and see if it helps:

```
refreshParent = function(){
    window.opener.reload();
    setTimeout(function(){ self.focus(); self.close(); }, 2000);           
}
```

Try using this:

**EDIT**: Removed true parameter from location.reload method, per W3 specification:

```
function CloseAndRefresh() { 
    parent.location.reload(); 
    self.close();
    return true;
}
```

See: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp

**EDIT**: Instead of adding it as a startup script, try just adding it to the ClientOnClick of the submit button, like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="return CloseAndRefresh();" OnClick="..." />
```

Comment: I think the issue is that it's never actually getting to the code.

I threw an alert to see if it ever gets called and it doesn't seem to be getting called at all.

Comment: I tried with the OnClientClick update, but I'm still not getting any type of response from the javascript.

Comment: @Jabsy: See edited answer. If you're not making it to that line, something before it is causing an error. I don't see any documentation where reload accepts a parameter.

Comment: I've tried it both way, with and without the "true" parameter and it works regardless.

I'm still not sure why the actual javascript doesn't seem to be getting called